# Allow Users to distribute Django Web App with data

Tags: python, django, progressive-web-apps, software-distribution

I'm creating a progressive web app with Django. I know the web app saves the state for offline use and one can install it locally to their computer. However, is there any way for that user to distribute their version of the website with saved cache and browser database to another person who doesn't have internet? Say via flash drive or from one local PC to the next without internet.

Comment: A valid PWA needs to be running in an https internet-connected browser and the user needs to explicitly agree to the install. There is no other way to install a PWA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an experimental web standard called [Web Packaging](https://web.dev/web-bundles/) that is working to allow sharing of websites in offline modes. It's not finalized and isn't supported in most browsers though.